# Simple Vlookup function not working for table array

Tags: arrays, excel, vlookup

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMzuf.png  Why on earth won't this work? it's so simple i made a new array and tested the same lookup value on that (the small bottom array) and it works fine. It's so simple i must be missing something equally simple?

Comment: sorry the error is called "Value not Available Error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem is that the values you want to search for are in the second column of your table, not the first. VLookup "searches for a value in the first column of a table array and returns a value in the same row from another column in the table array." (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) If you want to look up values by player name, instead of player ID, you'll need to change "A1:E13" to "B1:E13" so:

```
=VLOOKUP(C16, B1:E13, 2, 0)
```

Comment: there you go the answer was simple! thanks so much I would have scratched my head for ages :)